# select varchar dataype with commas as number

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in a database. it has a column name charges with datatype varchar. I want to change the data type to number. CAST functions don't work because it has commas. What could be a way to select data from the charges table as numeric? I can not alter the database.

```
select
  e. con_num,
  c.charge_date,
  cast(c.charges as number)
from employees e
left join charges c on e.con_num = c.con_num
```

Comment: Casting *might* work depending on your NLS settings; but it would be better to use `to_number()` and specify the format and group/decimal separators as part of that call. Some sample data and expected numeric equivalent would help though.

Comment: "I want to change the data type to number." - what does that mean? Change column's datatype (i.e. ALTER TABLE) or ...?

Comment: Alex is right; you are looking for `TO_NUMBER`. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/TO_NUMBER.html

Answer (score 3):

Use `TO_NUMBER` and specify the `NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS` as the third argument:

```sql
select e.con_num,
       c.charge_date,
       TO_NUMBER(c.charges, '999990D999', 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS=,.') AS charges
from   employees e
       left join charges c
       on e.con_num = c.con_num
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE employees (con_num) AS
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE charges (con_num, charge_date, charges) AS
SELECT 1, SYSDATE, '123,456' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | CON_NUM | CHARGE_DATE | CHARGES |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 2022-08-22 21:00:45 | 123.456 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=482196461e06153fab7c58fadfebdb12)*